# Entity Framework 4.1 "Code First" SetInitializer not being called again after Database.Delete

Tags: entity-framework, nunit, sql-server-ce-4

Trying to do some unit testing with EF 4.1 code first. I have my live db (SQL Server) and my unit test DB( Sql CE). After fighting (and losing) with EF, Sql CE 4.0 and Transaction support I decided the simplest way to run my test was to:

1. Create Db
2. Run Test
3. Delete Db
4. Rinse  and repeat

I have my [Setup] and  [TearDown] functions:

```
[SetUp]
public void Init()
{
    System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new MyTestContextInitializer());
    _dbContext = ContainerFactory.Container.GetInstance<IContext>();
    _testConnection = _dbContext.ConnectionString;
}

[TearDown]
public void Cleanup()
{
    _dbContext.Dispose();
    System.Data.Entity.Database.Delete(_testConnection);
}
```

Issue is that System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer does not call MyTestContextInitializer after the first test.

Hence the 2nd test then fails with:

> System.Data.EntityException : The
>   underlying provider failed on Open.
>   ----> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException
>   : The database file cannot be found.
>   Check the path to the database

TIA for any pointers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got around this by calling 'InitializeDatabase' manually. Like so:

```
   [SetUp]
    public void Init()
    {

        var initializer = new MyTestContextInitializer();
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(initializer);

        _dbContext = ContainerFactory.Container.GetInstance<IContext>();
        initializer.InitializeDatabase((MyTestContext)_dbContext);

        _testConnection = _dbContext.ConnectionString;
    }

    [TearDown]
    public void Cleanup()
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Database.Delete(_testConnection);

        _dbContext.Dispose();
    }
```

I think it may be a bug with EF 4.1 RC.

Comment: Lovely, that's helped me sort out what I thought was locking of the DB file (CE 4) between test fixtures. +1 :)

Comment: Brilliant! I had exactly this issue, with EF5 no less, and have been stuck on it a while.  This fixed it for me, thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug, the initializer set with

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer
```

is only called when the context is created for the first time in the AppDomain. Hence, since you're running all your tests in a single AppDomain, it's only called when the first test is ran.

Answer (score 1):

It took me almost a day to find out what caused my strange unittest behaviour: the database connection stayed open or the database was not created with a every new test. I searched everywhere for the root of the cause: MSTest (no Admin rights or where working copies of files somehow deleted?), SQL Server Express/CE (login failure?), Unity (objects not disposed?) or Entity Framework (no proper database initialization?). It turned out to be EF. Thanks a lot for the answer!